# Faster method to apply 1-D function along axis of 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a somewhat complex function that doesn't directly translate to np.vectorize (or sadly numba either), but has several numpy natively vectorized functions within.

I would like to speed up processing of these relatively large 3D arrays, and need to apply this function that takes a 1-D input/produces a 1D output along axis=2 (or axis=0 if I need to reshape the array).

Is there a faster way to do this than parallelizing the np.apply_along_axis function, splitting among threads, and splitting my data into 1-D arrays?

I will admit I'm not great with list comprehension if there's something I'm overlooking here.

I tried Dask's libraries as well, but the runtime was within seconds of this on an 8-core machine.

I've based the below code off similar answers I've found with parallelizing the np.apply_along_axis, and this does speed up the final result, but is still quite slow with large arrays.

```
import os, multiprocessing
import scipy
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def unpacking_apply_along_axis(all_args):
    (func1d, axis, arr) = all_args
    return np.apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr)

def parallel_apply_along_axis_spi(axis, arr):
    chunks = [(precip_2_spi_gh_func, axis, sub_arr)
              for sub_arr in np.array_split(arr, 500)]
    spipool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=16)
    individual_results = spipool.map(unpacking_apply_along_axis, chunks)
    spipool.close()
    spipool.join()
    
    return np.concatenate(individual_results)

def precip_2_spi_gh_func(ts):
##there are natively vectorized numpy functions within this section, but can't find anything that does it all natively##
    ts = np.array(ts)
    ##do some math
    return zs
```

To call the split function:

```
precip = np.random.uniform(0,300, size=(500,500,43))
#axis 2 is what I want to apply function on
spi = parallel_apply_along_axis_spi(2, precip)
```

Edits:

Here is the full function I'm calling with numpy.apply_along_axis.  It was translated to Python from another language that runs loops for i,j much faster than Python does...this works in Python, but is even slower than apply_along_axis.

```
def precip_2_spi_gh_func(ts):
    ts = np.array(ts)
    normthresh = 160.0
    min_posobs = 12 
    
    #transform rainfall into vector
    zdim = len(ts)
    pvals  = 0.0  # number of positive values
    psum   = 0.0  # sum of positive values
    logsum = 0.0
    
    pos_ids = np.where(ts > 0)
    pvals = float(len(pos_ids[0]))

    if pvals < min_posobs:
          return np.zeros(zdim) # not enough non-zeros
    #print (pvals)    

    posave = np.mean(ts[pos_ids])
    logsum = np.sum(np.log(ts[pos_ids]))

    norain_prob = (zdim - pvals) / zdim #calculate the percent of no rain events in the pixel array
    bigA = np.log(posave) - (logsum/pvals)
    #print ('bigA = ', bigA)
    shape = 0
    scale = 0
    if bigA > 0:
        shape = (1.0+np.sqrt((4.0*bigA/3.0)+1.0)) / (4.0*bigA)
        scale = posave / shape
    
    #if shape value is greater than 'normthresh' then calculate mean and std and use these for SPI
    if shape > normthresh:

        zs = scipy.stats.zscore(ts)

    # shape value is less than 'normthresh', so use gamma distribution to calculate the SPI values        
    if shape <= normthresh: 
        if pvals > 1:
            shape = np.double(shape)
            scale = np.double(scale)
            zs    = np.empty(zdim)
            prob = np.empty(zdim)
            
            for t in range (0,zdim):
                xi  = np.double(ts[t])
                if xi > 0:
                    pxi = scipy.special.gammainc(shape,xi/scale)
                elif xi == 0:
                    pxi = 0
                else:
                    pxi = np.nan

                prob[t] = norain_prob + ((1.0 - norain_prob) * pxi) # this is the prob of this event
                if norain_prob > 0.5:
                    if xi <= 7.0:
                        prob[t] = 0.5

                if np.sum(prob >= 1.0) > 0:
                    prob[np.where(prob >= 1.0)] = 0.99999999                 
                zs[t] = stats.norm.isf(1.0 - prob[t])
```

Numba code tried below, but returns several errors for native scipy/numpy functions.

```
@jit(parallel=True)
def precip_2_spi_gh_func(ts):
    normthresh = 160.0
    min_posobs = 12 
    
    #transform rainfall into vector
    zdim = len(ts)
    pvals  = 0.0  # number of positive values
    psum   = 0.0  # sum of positive values
    logsum = 0.0
    
    pos_ids = np.where(ts > 0)
    pvals = len(pos_ids[0])

    if pvals < min_posobs:
          return np.zeros(zdim) # not enough non-zeros
    #print (pvals)    

    posave = np.mean(ts[pos_ids])
    logsum = np.sum(np.log(ts[pos_ids]))

    norain_prob = (zdim - pvals) / zdim #calculate the percent of no rain events in the pixel array
    bigA = np.log(posave) - (logsum/pvals)
    #print ('bigA = ', bigA)
    shape = 0
    scale = 0
    if bigA > 0:
        shape = (1.0+np.sqrt((4.0*bigA/3.0)+1.0)) / (4.0*bigA)
        scale = posave / shape
    
    #if shape value is greater than 'normthresh' then calculate mean and std and use these for SPI
    if shape > normthresh:

        zs = (ts - np.mean(ts))/np.std(ts)

    # shape value is less than 'normthresh', so use gamma distribution to calculate the SPI values        
    if shape <= normthresh: 
        if pvals > 1:
            zs    = []
            prob = []
            
            for t in range (0,zdim):
                xi  = ts[t]
                if xi > 0:
                    pxi = scipy.special.gammainc(shape,xi/scale)
                elif xi == 0:
                    pxi = 0
                else:
                    pxi = np.nan

                prob[t] = norain_prob + ((1.0 - norain_prob) * pxi) # this is the prob of this event
                if norain_prob > 0.5:
                    if xi <= 7.0:
                        prob[t] = 0.5

                if np.sum(prob >= 1.0) > 0:
                    prob[np.where(prob >= 1.0)] = 0.99999999                 
                zs[t] = stats.norm.isf(1.0 - prob[t])          
    
    zs[np.isnan(zs)] = -9999
```

Comment: How is this question different from your previous (and now deleted) question?

Comment: In the end, it comes down to trying to either (1) rewrite the function in a vectorized way, (2) use GPU acceleration (such as by using PyTorch), or (3) rewrite the function in such a way that Numba can work (you said it doesn't work but don't explain why).

Comment: `np.apply_along_axis` is NOT a performance tool.  Pay attention to how it determines the shape (and dtype) of the return array.  That requires a trial calculation.  For a 2d input it's essentially a list comprehension with an array wrapper.  For 3d, it replaces a nested list comprehension, but does not reduce the total number of calls to your 1d array function.  In most cases it's those function calls that consumes the time, not the 'iteration' mechanism.  `apply` an make your code "prettier", but that's it.

Comment: If your code runs without error and produces the correct result then you may get better feedback on performance, style, technique if you repost your question over at the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `np.vectorize` has a performance disclaimer, which `apply...` forgets.  But testing has shown that `np.vectorize` can have a modest performance benefit with large arrays.  It has a `signature` parameter that could be used to imitate `apply...`, but that has a stronger performance disclaimer.   If you can't compile that action with `numba/cython`, I think you are reduced to doing time tests, and picking the one with (marginally) better times.

Comment: Added some context with the functions called above; felt like it took away from what I was hoping was a simple answer to iterate over the array that was just an aha! moment that I was missing.

Numba, unfortunately, throws lots of errors about the scipy functions within...could probably rewrite on my own, but don't understand some of the other errors it's throwing.

I've tried several other ways of feeding it 1-D arrays and multithreading those results, but none seems to be quicker than apply_along_axis when it has to return the values from the function BACK to the output array.